# Show function is order small o(t) for $t \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Show that$$\frac{1}{e^t-1} = \frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{12}t + o(t)$$
>   for $t\to 0$.

So what I need to show is that
$$\frac{1}{e^t - 1} - \frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{12}t + \frac{1}{2} = o(t)$$
for $t\to 0$ which can be restated as 
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\left |\frac{\frac{1}{e^t - 1} - \frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{12}t + \frac{1}{2}}{t} \right | = 0$$
which means that I have to show that the function $$f(t) := \frac{1}{t(e^t - 1)} - \frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{2t}$$ is continuous in $t_0 = 0$ with $f(0) = 0$. However I don't really know what to do from here, I can't find good estimations to work with $\epsilon - \delta$. I am looking for a very basic approach, possibly without methods from differential calculus. I know that $exp(x)$ grows faster than every polynomial and I am pretty sure this is of good use here, but I don't know how.

Comment: shouldn't it be $o(t^2)$?

Comment: The exercise says $o(t)$. Wolfram-Alpha calculates 0 for the limit too, so I suppose this is correct.

Comment: @SimpleArt It's likely $O(t^2)$, but since the expression is using small-oh, $o(t)$ might make more sense.

Comment: Compute the Taylor expansion of $\frac{t}{e^t - 1}$ about $0$ to sufficient order (order 3 or so) by expanding $e^t-1$, dividing by $t$, and developing the resulting quotient into a geometric series.

Comment: Are you allowed to split it into parts? $\dfrac 1 2 - \dfrac t {12}$ is $o(t)$ trivially, so you just need to prove the other summands are $o(t)$. But if this is for an assignment, they might not want you to do that.

Comment: @GFauxPas The limit is as $t$ approaches $0$, so $\frac{1}{2}$ is *not* $o(t)$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ah, silly me, you're absolutely right. I was thinking of  $t \to \infty$, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-e^t}&=\frac{1}{-t\left(1+\frac12t+\frac16t^2+O(t^3)\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{1-\frac12t+\frac{1}{12}t^2+O(t^3)}{-t}\\\\
&=-\frac1t+\frac12-\frac1{12}t+O(t^2)
\end{align}$$

Hence, we have

$$\frac{\frac{1}{1-e^2}+\frac1t-\frac12+\frac1{12}t}{t}=O(t)\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,t\to 0$$

Comment: Thanks. So this just follows from the definition of $exp(x)$. Why didn't I think of that!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And Happy Holidays!  -Mark

Comment: Can you tell me how you came up with your second step? How did the stuff go from the denominator to the numerator?

Comment: Sure.  Recall that $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2+O(x^3)$.  Now, let $x=\frac12t+\frac16t^2+O(t^3)$.

Comment: Okay, awesome. But where does that follow from? I think I am not allowed to use taylor expansions...

Comment: The geometric series.

Comment: Uh, of course, Thanks and have nice holidays too!

Comment: Pleased to hear that you have it now!  And thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're *given* the series expansion, it is fairly easy to check it.

First, observe that $\frac{1}{e^t-1}$ diverges as $t$ approaches $0$.  However,
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}\right)
$$ 
can be computed easily using l'Hopital's rule.  In particular,
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}\right)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{t-e^t+1}{t(e^t-1)}\right)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1-e^t}{(e^t-1)+te^t}\right)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{-e^t}{2e^t+te^t}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Now, we've confirmed the first term and discovered the second term.  In fact, we can consider the Taylor series of 
$$
\frac{t-e^t+1}{t(e^t-1)}.
$$
The first two terms are $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{12}t$.  Then, the remainder is $o(t)$ using Taylor's remainder theorem since the second derivative of the function is bounded near $t=0$.